# PYTHON. Как получить дату последнего сохранения источника?

Tags: python

Есть файл "text.xlsx", у которого необходимо извлечь дату последнего сохранения источника.
os.getmtime() - является датой изменения файла. [image: Свойства]

Comment: getctime - get cretaion time, getatime - get access time, getmtime - get modification time. Или я не понимаю твоего вопроса. Уточни пожалуйста. Дата на первом скриншоте храниться внутри самого xlsx документа.

Comment: @EugeneX , точно! Вы правильно поняли то, что мне нужно извлечь дату из xlsx документа. Можно ли это сделать с помощью pandas?

Comment: Не уверен, называется это - Workbook Properties попробуй поискать отходя от этого топика https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600566/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодарю за наводку [Eugene X](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/299914/eugene-x)! Для получение внутренней информации файлов с расширением .xlsx нам потребуется библиотека **openpyxl**.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file = load_workbook("foo.xlsx")
print(file.properties.modified)
#2021-11-11 11:11:11
```